Noether current of EM field under Lorentz transformation
There are two versions when deriving Noether's theorem, see (581172). One is where both the coordinates and fields are varied, leading to a total variation of a field $\phi'(x') = \phi(x) + \Delta \phi(x)$. The other is where we are only concerned with field variations $\phi'(x) = \phi(x) + \delta \phi(x)$. In the latter we can always reformulate coordinate variations as field variations, see (359199, 759877). For example, for an infinitesimal translation $x'^\mu = x^\mu - \epsilon^\mu$ of scalar fields $\psi(x)$, we can always utilize $\psi'(x') = \psi(x)$ to find the form of the field variations as $\psi'(x - \epsilon) = \psi(x) \rightarrow \psi'(x) = \psi(x + \epsilon) = \psi(x) + \partial_\lambda \psi(x) \epsilon^\lambda$.
If we start with field variations only (see Peskin&Schroeder), the conserved current is,
\begin{equation}
j^\mu = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi} \delta \phi - K^\mu
\end{equation}
for some field $K^\mu$ that satisfies $\mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L} + \delta \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L} + \partial_\mu K^\mu$.
Let us determine the conserved current of the electromagnetic field under Lorentz transformation. Let $x'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_{\; \nu} x^\nu$ be the Lorentz transformation of the coordinates and the infinitesimal version is $x'^\mu = x^\mu + \omega^\mu_{\;\nu} x^\nu$ where $\omega^\mu_{\;\nu}$ is an infinitesimal antisymmetric operator. A vector field $A_\nu(x)$ transforms as,
\begin{align}
& A'_\nu(x') = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\nu} A_\mu(x)\\
& A'_\nu(\Lambda x) = (\delta^\mu_{\; \nu} - \omega^\mu_{\;\nu}) A_\mu(x)\\
& A'_\nu(x) = (\delta^\mu_{\; \nu} - \omega^\mu_{\;\nu}) A_\mu(\Lambda^{-1} x)\\
& A'_\nu(x) = (\delta^\mu_{\; \nu} - \omega^\mu_{\;\nu}) A_\mu(x - \omega x)\\
& A'_\nu(x) = (\delta^\mu_{\; \nu} - \omega^\mu_{\;\nu}) (A_\mu(x) - \partial_\alpha A_\mu(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta)\\
& A'_\nu(x) = A_\nu(x) - A_\mu(x) \omega^\mu_{\;\nu} - \partial_\alpha A_\nu(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta, \qquad \text{up to order}\; \omega\\
& A'_\nu(x) = A_\nu(x) - A_\alpha(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu} - \partial_\alpha A_\nu(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta, \qquad \text{relabel}\; \mu \;\text{to}\; \alpha
\end{align}
Thus, the variation of the field is $\delta A_\nu(x) = - A_\alpha(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu} - \partial_\alpha A_\nu(x) \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta$. The variation of the electromagnetic field action is,
\begin{align}
\delta S & = -\frac{1}{4} \delta \int d^4x F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}\\ 
& = -\frac{1}{2} \int d^4x F^{\mu \nu} \delta F_{\mu \nu}\\
& = - \int d^4x F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu\\
& = \int d^4x F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu (\partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + A_\alpha \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu})\\
& = \int d^4x (F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\mu} + F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu A_\alpha \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu})\\
& = \int d^4x (F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta - F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha A_\mu \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu} + F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu A_\alpha \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu})\\
& = \int d^4x (F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \alpha} \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu})
\end{align}
In the second term of the third to the last line, the indices $\mu,\nu$ were switched then applied the antisymmetry of $F^{\mu\nu}$. So, $\delta \mathcal{L} = F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \alpha} \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu}$. I have to find a way to express this as $\partial_\alpha K^\alpha$. One can guess by trying to let $K^\alpha = -\mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta$ and checking if $\partial_\alpha (-\mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta) = F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \alpha} \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu}$.
\begin{align}
\partial_\alpha (-\mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta) & = \frac{1}{4} \partial_\alpha (F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu})\omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta - \mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\alpha}, \qquad \omega^\alpha_{\;\alpha} = 0\\
& = \frac{1}{2} F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha F_{\mu \nu} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta\\
& = F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha \partial_\mu A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta
\end{align}
This is equal to the first term of $\delta \mathcal{L}$, the only difference is the second term $F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \alpha} \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu}$. I'm not sure what to do with this or maybe the guess for $K^\alpha$ is incorrect. Any help?
If $K^\mu = -\eta^\mu_{\;\alpha} \mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta$ is correct then,
\begin{align}
j^\mu & = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu A_\nu} \delta A_\nu - K^\mu\\
& = -F^{\mu\nu} \delta A_\nu - K^\mu\\
& = F^{\mu\nu} \partial_\alpha A_\nu \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta + F^{\mu\nu} A_\alpha \omega^\alpha_{\;\nu} + \eta^\mu_{\;\alpha} \mathcal{L} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta
\end{align}
Due to the second term, I cannot write the energy-momentum tensor $T^\mu_{\; \alpha}$ as $j^\mu = T^\mu_{\; \alpha} \omega^\alpha_{\;\beta} x^\beta$. Any hints?

$F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu}{}^\alpha$ is symmetric in $\nu \leftrightarrow \alpha$ whereas $\omega_{\alpha\nu}$ is antisymmetric.

@Prahar How is it symmetric? Also, please see my added info at the end of the post. Is my Noether current correct? I'm not sure how to write the energy-momentum tensor due to a term. Maybe you can write your response as an answer so that I can accept it.

$F^{\mu\nu} F_\mu{}^\alpha$ is symmetric in $\nu \leftrightarrow \alpha$ whereas $\omega_{\alpha\nu}$ is antisymmetric. Consequently,
$$
F^{\mu\nu} F_\mu{}^\alpha \omega_{\alpha\nu} = 0 .
$$
The second term in your last equation can be written as
$$
F^{\mu\nu} A_\alpha \omega^\alpha{}_\nu  = - F^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu A_\alpha \omega^\alpha{}_\beta x^\beta + \partial_\nu  ( F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta )
$$
The first term above is of the form you want. A conserved current is only defined up to the shift $j^\mu \to j^\mu + \partial_\nu K^{\mu\nu}$ where $K^{\mu\nu} = - K^{\nu\mu}$. The second term is precisely of this form with $K^{\mu\nu} = F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta$ so we can simply drop it.

I'm trying to understand your last statement, where can I find more discussion about the current being defined up to a shift such that we can drop the shift?

Presumably any QFT textbook?

I've not seen any QFT books talk about this, e.g. Peskin, Greiner, Ryder, Schwartz, Maggiore, etc. Any recommendations?

Exercise 2.1 in P&S and similarly Exercise 3.3 in Schwartz explores similar ideas. Work them out and see how they apply to currents.

Just to clarify, we can drop the term $\partial_\nu  ( F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta )$ because when we take the divergence $\partial_\mu j^\mu + \partial_\mu \partial_\nu  ( F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta )$, the term $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu  ( F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta )$ vanishes hence $\partial_\nu  ( F^{\mu\nu} \omega^{\alpha\beta} A_\alpha x_\beta )$ is divergenceless. That is what you meant by drop the term. Thanks!

It’s more than that. That sort of term doesn’t contribute to the Noether charge either

Yes, because if we take the current to include a shift $j^\mu+\partial_\nu K^{\mu\nu}$, we have $\partial_\mu j^\mu+\partial_\mu\partial_\nu K^{\mu\nu}=0$. The last term is a contraction of a symmetric quantity $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$ and antisymmetric $K^{\mu\nu}$ so is always zero, thus we're always left with $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$. Then, $\int d^3x(\partial_0 j^0+\partial_i j^i)=0$, the second term vanishes assuming $j^i$ decays fast enough at infinity. We're left with the standard definition of the charge $Q = \int d^3x j^0$ which doesn't include the shift. Correct?

No, the idea is that the new charge $\int d^3 x j'^0$ is the same as the old charge $\int d^3 x j^0$.

Indeed, the new charge is the same as the old charge due to the fact that the divergence of $j'^\mu = j^\mu + \partial_\nu K^{\mu\nu}$ implies $\partial_\mu j'^\mu = \partial_\mu j^\mu$ since $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu K^{\mu\nu}=0$. Thus, $\partial_\mu j'^\mu = \partial_\mu j^\mu$ will lead to the result that the new charge is the same as the old charge. Note that we define charge from the fact that $\int d^3x \partial_0 j^0 = 0$ and define $Q=\int d^3x j^0$ so that $\partial_0 Q=0$. Isn't this the argument? If not, then what is?

That is NOT the argument. Of course it's true that both charges are conserved, because both currents are conserved. The point is actually that both charges are EQUAL.

The argument is that the new charge is $Q = \int d^3 x ( j^0 + \partial_\nu K^{0\nu} ) = \int d^3 x j^0 + \int d^3 x \partial_i K^{0i}$. The second then vanishes because its a total spatial derivative.

I see, thanks for clarifying that part!
